# Using Maven To Add Root Path

Tags: java, maven

I am using the `copy-maven-plugin` provided by `com.github.goldin`. I want to copy some files through Maven.

However, I don't want to hard code the path as the drive will be different. For example:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.github.goldin</groupId>
      <artifactId>copy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.2.5</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>create-archive</id>
          <phase>test</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>copy</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <resources>
              <resource>
                <targetPath>/../src/Server-Parent/src/test/resources</targetPath>
                <file>/../src/Server-Parent/DB/src/test/resources/mongoDB.xml</file>
                <destFileName>mongoDB.xml</destFileName>
              </resource>
            </resources>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

When I hard code for example, `C:\folder name\src\Server-Parent\src\test\resources` it works perfectly from any Maven project. However as soon as I put `../src` or `/../src` it contains problems.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.goldin:copy-maven-plugin:0.2.5:copy (c reate-archive) on project Server-Parent: Processing <resource> [Target p ath(s) [/../src/Server-Parent/src/test/resources], directory [C:/folder name\src/Server-Parent/DB/src/test/resources], dependencies []] fa iled with [java.lang.AssertionError]: [C:\folder name\src\Server-Parent\DB\sr c\test\resources] does not exist. Expression: d.directory -> [Help 1] [ERROR]
```

EDIT 2:

What I am trying to achive:

I have Server-Parent which is pom.xml containing pom value. Inside this is another Server-SubParent containing pom.xml pom value. Now inside this is Server-SubFunctionality containing jar.

Accoriding to your answer how can this be achived:

${project.basedir}

This are three projects where the Server-SubParent is a module of Server-Parent, but Server-SubParent is another pom containing another module containing the real functionality.

```
Server-Parent

 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <artifactId>Server-Parent</artifactId>
 <packaging>pom</packaging>

 <name>Server-Parent</name>

 <modules>
<module>Server-Sub-Parent</module>
 </modules>

Server-SubParent

 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
<groupId>com.server</groupId>
<artifactId>Server-Parent</artifactId>
<version>S06B1-RELEASE</version>
 </parent>

 <artifactId>Server-Sub-Parent</artifactId>
 <packaging>pom</packaging>

 <name>Server-Sub-Parent</name>

<modules>
<module>Server-Sub-ParentFunctionality</module>
</modules>

Server-Sub-Parent-Functionality

 <parent>
<groupId>com.server</groupId>
<artifactId>Server-Sub-Parent</artifactId>
<version>S06B1-RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>Server-Sub-Parent-Functionality</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Server-Sub-Parent-Functionality</name>
```

Comment: 'it contains problems.' *What problems?*

Comment: `/../src/` isn't a valid path construction, not on any OS I know of, especially not on Windows. What is the actual error, or this will be down voted and closed pretty quickly.

Comment: Please see edit above.

Comment: `C:\folder name\src\Server-Parent\DB\src\test\resources] does not exist.` Should it exist?

Comment: The path exists, but I would like the C:\folder name\ to be populated at runtime through Maven. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Server-Parent is a parent pom.xml and DB is another Maven project containing pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Try using maven predefined variables.

```
<resource>
                <targetPath>${project.basedir}/../src/Server-Parent/src/test/resources</targetPath>
                <file>${project.basedir}/../src/Server-Parent/DB/src/test/resources/mongoDB.xml</file>
                <destFileName>mongoDB.xml</destFileName>
              </resource>
```

Some helpful variables

```
${project.basedir}
${project.build.directory}
${project.build.sourceDirectory}
```

more info [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide)

Comment: Actually, I don't want to use this approach because I am on C:\some folder and other people are not. It could be C:\some folder2

Comment: hmmm... those variables are relative to the pom location. So no matter where you're the paths will stay the same

Comment: ok, suppose the parent project is Server-Parent containing pom value as pom.xml representing the super pom. Then inside this there are modules of Maven projects. So the first one is another parent called Server-SubParent. This is another pom.xml containing value of pom. Now the final stage is another Server-SubFunctionality containing jar. How would you specify the directory structure as what I am trying to do?

Comment: could you draw it with ASCII art or upload a picture. Can't really understand what're you trying to achieve

Comment: how do those projects relate to each other? are they all referencing parent-pom?

Comment: Yes, I have added an example above.

Comment: ok, and you want to move something from Server-Sub-Parent-Functionality to Server-Sub-Parent ?

Comment: No, I would like to copy resources independant of the path. So in this case I would like to copy a resource into the Server-Sub-Functionality. The example may be wrong, but I think you know what I mean now. I would like to copy a resource meaning that it will work on all machines. So the hard coding of the C:\folder name is not needed.